# Codeigniter Contact form submission returning 500 error.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

So I am trying to create a Contact form.

HTML / view:

```
            <form action="" class="horizontal-form" id="contact-form" method="post">
                <h3 class="form-section">Help Form</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-12" name="name" id="name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" >Email</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-12" name="email" id="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" >Issues / Feedback</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control col-md-12" rows="3" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="margin-top-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Send</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

javascript(inside of document.ready):

```
            $('#contact-form').validate({
                rules: {
                    name: {
                        minlength: 2,
                        required: true
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    message: {
                        minlength: 2,
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                highlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
                },
                success: function(element) {
                    element.text('OK!').addClass('valid').closest('.control-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'contact_process',
                        data: $('#contact-form').serialize(),
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(data) {
                            $("#contact-form").hide('slow');
                            $('#results').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Support Controller contact_process action:

```
public function contact_process() {      
    $this->load->library('email');
    //grab the post data
    $this->email->from($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('name'));
    $this->email->to('bgarrison@cognigencorp.com');
    $this->email->subject('Cognigen Helpdesk Request');
    $this->email->message($this->input->post('message'));

    if ($this->email->send()) {
        echo "We have successfully received your email. We will Contact you ASAP.";
    } else {
        echo "Some problem occurred.";
    }
}
```

As you can see my form is being validated and then submitted to index.php/support/contact_process. However when it does I get `An Error Was Encountered
The action you have requested is not allowed.` and a 500 server error. When I go to the url manually it works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

```
          submitHandler: function(form) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'contact_process',
                    data: $('#contact-form').serialize(),
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#contact-form").hide('slow');
                        $('#results').html(data);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
```

to this:

```
          var site_url ="<?php echo(site_url('/support/contact_process')); ?>";
          submitHandler: function(form) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: site_url,
                    data: $('#contact-form').serialize(),
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#contact-form").hide('slow');
                        $('#results').html(data);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: the javascript is not a php file so it cannot handle php in it

Comment: use the url of your site for example http://www.yoursite.com/support/contact_process like a simple url @BillGarrison

Comment: Im not having issues with the URL. The url is correct. It is going to the correct place but when it gets there its giving a 500 error. However, this only happens when trying to make the ajax call. If i copy and paste from the debugger into the browser it works fine (except for the fact that the post variables arent there obviously)

Comment: Just to satiate curiosity i added in the full URL of my site as the url for the ajax call. Still nothing I get a 500. Yet going to it manually works fine